# Ungraceful shutdown (hard-drive spinning while powered off)

Tags: hard-drive, kubuntu, hardware, shutdown, system

Most times (not always) during shutdown of my kubuntu laptop, the hard drive make a noise as if it was powered off without warning.

How can I ensure the system waits until everything is ok before it powers off?

Running Kubuntu 14.04 on a 2006 Toshiba laptop

Edit: as a temporary solution, I'm now using the command `sudo shutdown -H now` making the system halt instead of power off after shutdown, then I have to press the power button for 3 seconds to force a power off. The hard-drive doesn't make the noise that way.

Comment: I would assume that typing `sync` twice on command line will still flush the system (as we used to have to do in the old times). (see `man sync` ;) )

Comment: Do you mean that you hear it  suddenly spinning up or suddenly spinning down during power off?

Comment: It suddenly spins down, going from a very loud high pitch to inaudible low frequencies in the span of about 0.5 second or less.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to comment. I guess this answer may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1293496/815916

Answer (score 0):

> during shutdown of my kubuntu laptop, the hard drive make a noise as if it was powered off without warning.
>   How can I ensure the system waits until everything is ok before it powers off?

Unless there's some evil bug, I don't believe that's happening. Your HDD might make such a noise, but unless you have very strong evidence to believe otherwise, your system makes sure that everything is OK before powering off.

Comment: I don't know if that's proof, but I don't see the usual kubuntu logo with shutdown information messages either. It just goes from the desktop to a blank screen and abruptly powers off. I've had this laptop for a long time and the hard-drive doesn't make such a noise when powered off normally. Could it be something to do with overheating like in that comment? [link]http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10522

Comment: Hmm, that's something different though. Please check your logfiles if there's anything interesting...

Comment: What should I look for exactly? I'm thinking of looking through the logs using the KSystemLog utility

Comment: Oh sorry: look into /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages...

Comment: It seems my syslog, syslog.1 and syslog.2.gz files don't go back far enough in history, only a few hours. No sign of /var/log/messages . I'll check logs after it happens again.