# Ubuntu Shutdown While the Machine (Laptop) Fan is Still Running

Tags: 18.04, dell, power-management, shutdown, hardware

I use Ubuntu 18.04. 
Whenever I shutdown (power off) my laptop (my laptop is Dell G7 15), there is a sound "klack" from the laptop. It sounds as if I force shutdown of my machine by clicking the power button while the OS still running.

I suspected that, whenever I do shutdown, it seems the OS has been "turned off", but the machine seems "not yet ready" to turn off.

My workaround to this issue is, whenever I want to turn off my laptop, I will do the following:

1. Restart the laptop
2. Run the command "sudo halt"
3. Wait for some minutes, listen to the sound of the fan. If it is already stopped, then press the power button to turn off the machine

However, this workaround does not always work since sometimes, after executing sudo halt, the fan is still running for more than 30 minutes. So, since I no longer able to wait for it to turn off, I am forced to press the power button to turn off the machine, and when I do that, I hear the sound "klack".

I am quite sure that when I run "sudo halt", the OS seems already turn off, it is just the machine hardware (the fan) which for some reason, is not able to turn off.

How to solve this issue? how can I safely shutdown both the OS and hardware? 
I have tried to update my kernel, and this problem still persists. I am afraid this problem may eventually break my motherboard.

Thank you very much for your help! I would appreciate any hints that you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I solved this problem by doing the following:

- Updated the Ubuntu kernel
- Updated the BIOS
- Installed the latest graphics card driver
- Go to /etc/default/grub, and change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" instead of "nomodeset"

Now, everytime I want to turn off my PC, I restart it and upon restart, I run the command "sudo shutdown -H now", then press the power button.

This looks like solving the problem, since I have been able to shut down my machine smoothly for the past 1 month.