# Help me troubleshoot my slow boot time ( more than 2 min )

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS in my Dell Inc. Inspiron 3542 using 4 gigs ram and NVD7. It takes more than 1 to 5 min ever time to simply boot the OS (Not using any dual-boot).

Here are the logs of `systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 4.336s (kernel) + 1min 24.904s (userspace) = 1min 29.241s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 24.704s in userspace
```

and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @1min 24.704s
└─multi-user.target @1min 24.704s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @42.547s +42.156s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @42.497s +47ms
      └─network.target @42.484s
        └─NetworkManager.service @27.289s +15.192s
          └─dbus.service @27.284s
            └─basic.target @27.238s
              └─sockets.target @27.237s
                └─cups.socket @41.919s
                  └─sysinit.target @26.973s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @25.440s +1.532s
                      └─apparmor.service @23.525s +1.886s
                        └─local-fs.target @23.506s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration.mnt.mount @1min 7.735s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 412ms
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @6.342s
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @5.768s +573ms
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @4.961s +777ms
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.809s +147ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @4.515s
                                        └─-.mount @4.482s
                                          └─-.slice @4.481s
```

I am also facing laptop fan issue **which does not turn off** even after complete system shutdown ( This issue is all Linux distro ( tries fedora and had the same issue) but in windows it was working fine.

New to linux and any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : `systemd-analyze blame`

```
42.156s plymouth-quit-wait.service
31.779s snapd.service
26.206s udisks2.service
24.892s networkd-dispatcher.service
21.546s logrotate.service
20.895s containerd.service
19.196s accounts-daemon.service
17.187s power-profiles-daemon.service
16.689s polkit.service
16.256s dev-sda2.device
15.707s gpu-manager.service
15.192s NetworkManager.service
15.178s avahi-daemon.service
15.175s bluetooth.service
13.679s switcheroo-control.service
13.671s thermald.service
13.667s systemd-logind.service
13.580s wpa_supplicant.service
13.531s systemd-journal-flush.service
10.101s dev-loop16.device
 9.853s dev-loop6.device
 9.436s dev-loop13.device
 9.426s dev-loop2.device
lines 1-23...skipping...
42.156s plymouth-quit-wait.service
31.779s snapd.service
26.206s udisks2.service
24.892s networkd-dispatcher.service
21.546s logrotate.service
20.895s containerd.service
19.196s accounts-daemon.service
17.187s power-profiles-daemon.service
16.689s polkit.service
16.256s dev-sda2.device
15.707s gpu-manager.service
15.192s NetworkManager.service
15.178s avahi-daemon.service
15.175s bluetooth.service
13.679s switcheroo-control.service
13.671s thermald.service
13.667s systemd-logind.service
13.580s wpa_supplicant.service
13.531s systemd-journal-flush.service
10.101s dev-loop16.device
 9.853s dev-loop6.device
 9.436s dev-loop13.device
 9.426s dev-loop2.device
 9.236s secureboot-db.service
 8.913s dev-loop21.device
 8.775s dev-loop14.device
 8.639s dev-loop20.device
 8.585s dev-loop10.device
 8.567s dev-loop9.device
 8.565s dev-loop17.device
 8.559s dev-loop24.device
 8.036s dev-loop12.device
 7.984s dev-loop23.device
 7.978s dev-loop22.device
 7.910s dev-loop15.device
 7.812s dev-loop1.device
 7.777s dev-loop18.device
 7.680s systemd-modules-load.service
 7.675s ModemManager.service
 7.641s dev-loop19.device
lines 1-40






































42.156s plymouth-quit-wait.service
31.779s snapd.service
26.206s udisks2.service
24.892s networkd-dispatcher.service
21.546s logrotate.service
20.895s containerd.service
19.196s accounts-daemon.service
17.187s power-profiles-daemon.service
16.689s polkit.service
16.256s dev-sda2.device
15.707s gpu-manager.service
15.192s NetworkManager.service
15.178s avahi-daemon.service
15.175s bluetooth.service
13.679s switcheroo-control.service
13.671s thermald.service
13.667s systemd-logind.service
13.580s wpa_supplicant.service
13.531s systemd-journal-flush.service
10.101s dev-loop16.device
 9.853s dev-loop6.device
 9.436s dev-loop13.device
 9.426s dev-loop2.device
 9.236s secureboot-db.service
 8.913s dev-loop21.device
 8.775s dev-loop14.device
 8.639s dev-loop20.device
 8.585s dev-loop10.device
 8.567s dev-loop9.device
 8.565s dev-loop17.device
 8.559s dev-loop24.device
 8.036s dev-loop12.device
 7.984s dev-loop23.device
 7.978s dev-loop22.device
 7.910s dev-loop15.device
 7.812s dev-loop1.device
 7.777s dev-loop18.device
```

Comment: Would you please post your `systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: I have updated the question with `systemd-analyze blame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to reduce that amount of time:

1. deactivate plymouth boot screen

- Open the terminal, type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and hit
  enter.
- Look for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`  (or something like this) line and change it to
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet"`.
- save and close the file. Then type `sudo update-grub` and press enter.

2. Apparently, snaps are "killing" you. Unless you're a fan of them, I would recommend to get rid of all and use flatpaks instead:

- to get rid of snaps you can open the terminal and type: `sudo apt purge -y snapd && rm -rf ~/snap && sudo rm -rf /snap && sudo rm -rf /var/snap && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd && sudo apt-mark hold snap`.
  Be aware that will remove your Mozilla Firefox, since it is a snap.
- in order to use flatpaks on ubuntu just type in a terminal `sudo apt install -y flatpak && flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo` and, after that, you can install Firefox by typing `flatpak install -y flathub org.mozilla.firefox`. It may be necessary a reboot before you can use it.
- also, since snaps are gone, you'll need to install the gnome software and the flatplak plugin to it, by typing `sudo apt install -y gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-flatpak`.

3. There's another minor improvement you can do that is to avoid waiting for the computer to go online on the initialization. That can be done by typing `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` in a terminal an hitting enter.

These three adjustments will dramatically reduce your boot time in comparison with what it is now.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: You have any idea about the fan issue.

Comment: About the fan, this link might help:         https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270406/ubuntu-shutdown-while-the-machine-laptop-fan-is-still-running#:~:text=Restart%20the%20laptop,to%20turn%20off%20the%20machine